# Using two different math libraries in the same project confuses Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, redefinition

My project needs to use both Micorsoft Visual C++ `math.h` and Intel MKL `math.h`.

Building with verbose details, I get:

```
1>  Note: including file:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath
1>  Note: including file:         E:\3rdParty\MKL\2017.1.143\windows\compiler\include\math.h
1>  Note: including file:          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\../../vc/include/math.h
1>  Note: including file:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>  E:\3rdParty\MKL\2017.1.143\windows\compiler\include\math.h(1577): warning C4005: 'HUGE_VALF' : macro redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\../../vc/include/math.h(104) : see previous definition of 'HUGE_VALF'
1>  E:\3rdParty\MKL\2017.1.143\windows\compiler\include\math.h(1579): warning C4005: 'HUGE_VALL' : macro redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\../../vc/include/math.h(105) : see previous definition of 'HUGE_VALL'
1>  E:\3rdParty\MKL\2017.1.143\windows\compiler\include\math.h(1581): warning C4005: 'HUGE_VAL' : macro redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\../../vc/include/math.h(96) : see previous definition of 'HUGE_VAL'
```

The "'HUGE_VALF' : macro redefinition" message is the one that made me be suspicious.

At first I just disabled that warning, but considering that this option would only mask a potential problem, I am looking for an alternative solution.

From lines 1 and 2, you can see that Visual Studio's `cmath` does not include Visual Studio's `math.h`, as it should, but MKL's file with the same name.

How can I set my `CMakeLists.txt` file so that the compiler can pick the right include files?

Comment: Look in your project's `Properties\Configuration Properties\C/C++\General` and the top entry `Additional Include Directories`. Is `E:\3rdParty\MKL\2017.1.143\windows\compiler\include` there? If it is, try putting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include;` before it (if `math.h` is even in that directory,  you'd better check).

Comment: @TedLyngmo - The paths are already sorted as you indicate. I confirm `math.h` is in that include directory.

Comment: Ok, is there some `#ifdef` in the `cmath` file that prevents `cmath` from `#include`ing `math.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap one library.

For example, create header file:

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace imath {
    double sin(double a);
}
```

And in cpp

```cpp
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include <intel/math.h>

namespace imath {
    double sin(double a) {
        return ::sin(a);
    }
}
```

Do this for every symbol you need to use in common source.

And do not include `C` version of `math.h` you are using C++ so `#include <cmath>`.